# multiple dispatches with callback in react-hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

how to add `loading` state to true in 'addItem' (reducer case), and set the `loading` state to false?

But I'm stuck using react-hook
https://codesandbox.io/s/new-water-vczdp

I did it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-todolist-3dko3 with older react version.

What to do here?

```
case "addItem": {
      //fakeHttp();

      const { toAddItem, items } = state;
      const nextId = +items[items.length - 1].id + 1;

      return {
        items: [...items, { id: nextId, name: toAddItem }],
        loading: false
      };
    }
```

Comment: I think you need some kind of semafor that counts outgoing requests increased on request to server and is decreased after request response is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call async functions in your reducer. You have to use other hooks for this. In your case, you should use `useCallback` hook:

```
function App() {
  const [{ items, toAddItem, loading }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    initialState
  );

  const addItem = useCallback(() => {
    async function fakeHttp() {
      dispatch({ type: "loading" });
      await delay(500);
      dispatch({ type: "addItem"})
    }
    fakeHttp();
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
    <AddList
        handleInput={e =>
          dispatch({ type: "handleInput", value: e.target.value })
        }
        toAddItem={toAddItem}
        addItem={addItem}
        loading={loading}
      />
  )
}
```

I make some changes in your sandbox example. You could see a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-currying-l39il

Comment: what if I don't want to name function as fakeHttp? just like so ```const addItem = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch({ type: "loading" });
    await delay(500);
    dispatch({ type: "addItem" });
  }, []);```

Comment: I manage to make it work without useCallback: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-merkle-s4tw0

Comment: @RachelV yes, you can do this without `useCallback`. But in this case functions `addItem` and `deleteItem` will be recreated on each render of the component `App`. And this will cause the re-rendering of all `List` items and `AddList` component on each render of `App` because you always pass new props to them.

Comment: what's the rule of thumb of when to use `useCallback`?

Comment: @RachelV you have to use `useCallback` hook every time when you need to prevent unnecessary render of your child components and optimize performance. Read more about `useCallback` here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback